# Get name based on input from list dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Based upon input value, I need to get corresponding name. I have my input my_list which contains name, min_size and max_size. If input value is falls under min_size and max_size, we need return corresponding name

Below code is working fine, but can we improve this in terms of performance and readability by adding any mapping functionality?

code

```
import random
my_list  = [
            {"name": "bob01", "min_size": 0, "max_size": 100, "capacity": 200},
            {"name": "bob02", "min_size": 101, "max_size": 1000, "capacity": 100},
            {"name": "bob03", "min_size": 1001, "max_size": 5000, "capacity": 50},
            {"name": "bob04", "min_size": 5001, "max_size": 10000, "capacity": 25},
            {"name": "bob05", "min_size": 10001, "max_size": 50000, "capacity": 12},
            {"name": "bob06", "min_size": 50001, "max_size": 100000, "capacity": 6},
            {"name": "bob07", "min_size": 100001, "max_size": 150000, "capacity": 3},
            {"name": "bob08", "min_size": "any", "max_size": "any", "capacity": 1}
        ]
def get_name(n):
    for person in my_list:
        try:
            min = person['min_size']
            max = person['max_size']
            if min <= n <= max:
                return person['name']
        except TypeError:
            return person['name'] 

for i in range(10):
    n = random.randint(0, 170000)
    print("My load is ", n)
    name = (get_name(n))
    print("Mr {} can handle this load".format(name))
```

Comment: The only change I'd personally do would be to create a dict with `name` as the key. It doesn't change the fact you've still got to iterate over it. Also don't set variable names as `min` and `max` because you're overriding the functions.

Comment: What if more than one person fit the min/max size criteria?

Comment: Is `my_list` already sorted like that? Or are there cases when it's not sorted?

Comment: @Peter, This what you are suggesting "bob01": {"min_size": 0, "max_size": 100, "capacity": 200} ? and yes, min, max is bad to use variables

Comment: @timgeb, first matching person is enough, this design actually should fir same values, everyboady has unique capabilities

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano yes , it already sorted most of the case, but some times they may not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If `my_list` is just 8 items, my answer might just be a negligible micro-optimization.

Iterating the whole `my_list` of length `n` just to get the corresponding name for every chosen number of length `m` would result to a time complexity of `O(n * m)`. Thus if `my_list` is 8 items and we would get the name of 100,000 numbers, this means we would be iterating 800,000 times on worst cases.

An improvement is by storing a sorted list of all `min_size`. Then, for every chosen number, we don't need to iterate over the whole `my_list`, we just need to perform a binary search on the smallest number of `min_size` possible. This would result to `O(nlogn + mlogn)` operation. Thus if `my_list` is 8 items and we would get the name of 100,000 numbers, this means we would be iterating 300,024 times on worst cases. This is at the expense of additional `O(n)` in space complexity.

```
import bisect
import random

my_list  = [
    {"name": "bob01-0", "min_size": 0, "max_size": 100, "capacity": 200},
    {"name": "bob02-101", "min_size": 101, "max_size": 1000, "capacity": 100},
    {"name": "bob03-1001", "min_size": 1001, "max_size": 5000, "capacity": 50},
    {"name": "bob04-5001", "min_size": 5001, "max_size": 10000, "capacity": 25},
    {"name": "bob05-10001", "min_size": 10001, "max_size": 50000, "capacity": 12},
    {"name": "bob06-50001", "min_size": 50001, "max_size": 100000, "capacity": 6},
    {"name": "bob07-100001", "min_size": 100001, "max_size": 150000, "capacity": 3},
    {"name": "bob08-last", "min_size": "any", "max_size": "any", "capacity": 1},  # The last
    # {"name": "bob08-last", "min_size": 150001, "max_size": "any", "capacity": 1},  # This could also be the last
    # {"name": "bob08-last", "min_size": 150001, "max_size": "17000+", "capacity": 1},  # This could also be the last
]

# O(n) operation. Setup a hash table so that getting the name based on min_size will just be O(1).
my_dict = {
    data["min_size"]: data
    for data in my_list
}

# O(n log n) operation as we need to sort. Collect all the min_size and sort it.
min_sizes = sorted(
    [data["min_size"] for data in my_list if isinstance(data["min_size"], int)]
)

def get_name(n):
    # O(log n) operation. Perform a binary search on the sorted list to know the corresponding min_size.
    n_index = bisect.bisect_left(min_sizes, n)

    if n_index == len(min_sizes):
        if not isinstance(my_dict[min_sizes[-1]]["max_size"], int) \
                or my_dict[min_sizes[-1]]["max_size"] >= n:
            return my_dict[min_sizes[-1]]["name"]
        else:
            return my_dict["any"]["name"]
    elif min_sizes[n_index] == n:
        return my_dict[min_sizes[n_index]]["name"]
    elif min_sizes[n_index] > n:
        return my_dict[min_sizes[n_index-1]]["name"]

# O(m) operation. Process all input numbers.
for i in range(10):
    n = random.randint(0, 170000)
    print("My load is", n)
    name = (get_name(n))
    print("Mr {} can handle this load".format(name))
```

Output:

```
My load is 22288
Mr bob05-10001 can handle this load
My load is 6296
Mr bob04-5001 can handle this load
My load is 153706
Mr bob08-last can handle this load
My load is 72470
Mr bob06-50001 can handle this load
My load is 36776
Mr bob05-10001 can handle this load
My load is 112478
Mr bob07-100001 can handle this load
My load is 67958
Mr bob06-50001 can handle this load
My load is 69366
Mr bob06-50001 can handle this load
My load is 56379
Mr bob06-50001 can handle this load
My load is 119832
Mr bob07-100001 can handle this load
```

Comment: what if last value like this,  {"name": "bob08", "min_size": 150001, "max_size": "any", "capacity": 1} or  {"name": "bob08", "min_size": 150001, "max_size": "17000+", "capacity": 1}, instead of "min_size": "any", sorry my input not covered in question, just while testing now, I am thinking to support this kind of inputs

Comment: I believe what you mean by `"max_size": "17000+"` is `"max_size": 17000` right? As having the `+` sign would make it `150001-17000+` which seems odd as a range as it is equivalent to `150001-infinity`.

Comment: its typo, its actually, {"name": "bob08", "min_size": 150001, "max_size": "170000+",

Comment: @Vidya I updated the answer to also accept "any" for the max_size part. You can check it if it fits your requirements :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is already considerably efficient. Just I would suggest to remove the `try` `except` block for more efficiency:

```
def get_name(n):
    for person in my_list:
        if isinstance(person['min_size'], int) and isinstance(person['max_size'], int):
            if person['min_size'] <= n <= person['max_size']:
                return person['name']
        else:
            return person['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dataclass and type hints makes the code much more readable and easier to maintain

```
import random
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    min_size: int
    max_size: int
    capacity: int


my_list = [
    {"name": "bob01", "min_size": 0, "max_size": 100, "capacity": 200},
    {"name": "bob02", "min_size": 101, "max_size": 1000, "capacity": 100},
    {"name": "bob03", "min_size": 1001, "max_size": 5000, "capacity": 50},
    {"name": "bob04", "min_size": 5001, "max_size": 10000, "capacity": 25},
    {"name": "bob05", "min_size": 10001, "max_size": 50000, "capacity": 12},
    {"name": "bob06", "min_size": 50001, "max_size": 100000, "capacity": 6},
    {"name": "bob07", "min_size": 100001, "max_size": 150000, "capacity": 3},
    {"name": "bob08", "min_size": "any", "max_size": "any", "capacity": 1}
]
persons = [Person(**entry) for entry in my_list if
           isinstance(entry['min_size'], int) and isinstance(entry['max_size'], int)]


def get_name(load: int) -> Optional[str]:
    person: Person
    for person in persons:
        if person.min_size <= load <= person.max_size:
            return person.name
    return None


for i in range(10):
    print(f'------------{i}----------------')
    load = random.randint(0, 170000)
    print(f"My load is {load}")
    name = (get_name(load))
    if name is not None:
        print(f"Mr {name} can handle this load")
    else:
        print("No one can handle this load")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a `Person` class, then you can implement custom behaviour to do checks. Here's an example of how you'd do it:

```
import random

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, min_size, max_size, capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.min_size = min_size
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.capacity = capacity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def can_carry_load(self, n):
        if self.min_size is None:
            if self.max_size is None:
                return True
            return n <= self.max_size
        if self.max_size is None:
            return self.min_size <= n
        return self.min_size <= n <= self.max_size


my_list = [
    Person("bob01", min_size=0, max_size=100, capacity=200),
    Person("bob02", min_size=101, max_size=1000, capacity=100),
    Person("bob03", min_size=1001, max_size=5000, capacity=50),
    Person("bob04", min_size=5001, max_size=10000, capacity=25),
    Person("bob05", min_size=10001, max_size=50000, capacity=12),
    Person("bob06", min_size=50001, max_size=100000, capacity=6),
    Person("bob07", min_size=100001, max_size=150000, capacity=3),
    Person("bob08", min_size=None, max_size=None, capacity=1),
]

def get_name(n):
    for person in my_list:
        if person.can_carry_load(n):
            return str(person)


for i in range(10):
    n = random.randint(0, 170000)
    print(f"My load is {n}")
    name = get_name(n)
    print(f"Mr {name} can handle this load")
```

(You may possibly be able to mix this answer with the dataclass one, it's just not something I have any experience with)

I changed `"any"` to `None`, because checking for `None` is a lot more pythonic than catching the `TypeError` when you attempt to compare strings to integers.

I also switched to using f-strings as they are useful things worth knowing about, assuming you're on a recent version of Python.